# Total number of times a substring can be found in a string

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, substring

I am having a hard time understanding the code below.. Especially the last line.

```
string = "abcdcdc"

sub_string = "cdc"

print(sum([1 for i in range(0, len(string) - len(sub_string) + 1) if (string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)] == sub_string)]))
```

Output of the code is `'2'`.

This code write the times of number the substring found in the string given above.

Any explanation would be appreciated .

Comment: because `'cdc'` appears in `'abcdcdc'` 2 times?

Comment: Can you explain please. Because thats what i am searching for.

Comment: @Farhan.K, please stop the condescension. The question is very clear: the user wants an explanation of the code, not the result. It's a good question +1.

Comment: @jpp it wasn't before the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[1 for i in range(0, len(string) - len(sub_string) + 1) if (string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)] == sub_string)]
```

means **loop** `i` in range from `0` upto `len(string) - len(sub_string) + 1` (not including) and **if** a substring of `string` at index `i` and with length of `sub_string` (i.e. upto index `(len(sub_string) + i)`) is equal to `sub_string` **then take** `1` and **collect them** as list, i.e. the result is `[1, 1]` because `substring` is a substring of `string` two times.

See [Python List Comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension) for more details.

---

`sum([1 for i in range(0, len(string) - len(sub_string) + 1) if (string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)] == sub_string)])`

It just sums the list described above, `sum([1, 1])` equals to `2`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It really helped me understanding the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you view the list of values generated by the for loop you will find it creates the list below:

```
print([string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)] for i in range(0, len(string) - len(sub_string) + 1)])
['abc', 'bcd', 'cdc', 'dcd', 'cdc']
```

The list contains the substring you are searching for twice which is the result you obtain.

Answer (score 0):

The code loops over the string indices from the start of "string" to the end minus the number of elements in subsring.

The [] crates a list and 1 is wrtitten in there if the next 3 elements of the string are the same as sub_string.

sum() returns the sum of the list. Since you included a 1 everytime you found sub_string, this counts the number of occurances of sub_string in string

Answer (score 0):

its python so you have to read it backwards, 'if string contains substring, try to find number of substring occurrences.'  I'd write it this way:

```
 'abcdcdc'.count('cdc')
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a so called [**list comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), which has this syntax, that is why it may look like an `if` without visible outcome placed in a `for` loop.

The steps are not complicated otherwise:

- we need all 3-character subsequences from the big string, the `range(0, len(string) - len(sub_string) + 1)` part prepares the starting indices for those, 7-3+1=5, so the range will run from 0...4. You can check it in the interactive shell, it will say `range(0,5)`
- then the `[]` thing creates a list, you can check that too: `[1 for i in range(0,5)]` will create `[1,1,1,1,1]`
- but you want to compare things, with the `if` part. First you could check the substrings, instead of `1`, write the substring thing: `[string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)] for i in range(0,5)]`, as Karl Graham suggests and resulting in `['abc', 'bcd', 'cdc', 'dcd', 'cdc']`, then you could use the full comparison, `[string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)]==sub_string for i in range(0,5)]`, which produces `[False, False, True, False, True]`
- in fact you can `sum` this already, `sum([string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)]==sub_string for i in range(0,5)])` will output 2, because `True` is counted as 1 and `False` as 0. Just here whoever created this code, decided to output actual numbers and used the optional `if` clause for the list comprehension, creating a list of 1-s, but only for the two matching positions: `[1 for i in range(0, len(string) - len(sub_string) + 1) if (string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)] == sub_string)]` displays `[1,1]`
- and `sum` adds those 1-s together, resulting in 2.

Summary code for running as Python snippet or in a notebook (like [here](https://try.jupyter.org/)):

```
string = "abcdcdc"
sub_string = "cdc"
print(len(string))
print(len(sub_string))
print(range(0,len(string)-len(sub_string)+1))
print([1 for i in range(0,5)])
print([string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)] for i in range(0,5)])
print([string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)]==sub_string for i in range(0,5)])
print(sum([string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)]==sub_string for i in range(0,5)]))
print([1 for i in range(0, len(string) - len(sub_string) + 1) if (string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)] == sub_string)])
print(sum([1 for i in range(0, len(string) - len(sub_string) + 1) if (string[i:(len(sub_string) + i)] == sub_string)]))
```